# Where should I start in the Hadith?

Tags: hadith

I just downloaded the Hadith from Amazon for $0.99 - its massive! Where should I start? What are the most central parts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic as it is about 'Questions on Muslim culture or behaviour unrelated to the teachings of Islam are off-topic here. See: [Islam SE: Not an Muslim Peer Support Group.](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-an-muslim-peer-support-group)'

Comment: This is a question you should ask yourself before the download.

Answer (score 1):

There are no guidelines on how to read narrations or what order to read them in, however it is worth noting that Muslims try to seek guidance through the Quran and Sunnah (Prophetic Tradition) and go about their lifes by trying to implement what they learn, therefore if you want to find out how a Muslim should react in a certain situation then look for the relevant narrations, not all are authentic and each may have been graded.

This question will be closed soon as it will attract opinion based answers such as this one.